# Invalid provider type specified error in code signing the vsto outlook application

Tags: outlook, vsto, clickonce, code-signing, pfx

I brought a code signing certificate from GoDaddy generated a .pfx file from it. But when I use this file to code sign the clickonce manifest of my outlook vsto application I get this error in visual studio

```
An error occurred while signing: Invalid provider type specified.
```

What could be the problem here?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this something you have tried? [Signing clickonce manifests gives error](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/44rdf0/signing_clickonce_manifests_gives_error/)

Comment: Hi @SlavaIvanov 
Well, I tried converting the pfx by this command in open ssl `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert-cng.pfx -out mycert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.pem -out mycert-cryptoapi.pfx`  then added the new pfx file but when i build the solution I get his error `Cannot import the following key file: mycert-cryptoapi.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_xxxxxx`

Comment: I believe the [article](https://remyblok.tweakblogs.net/blog/11803/converting-certificate-to-use-csp-storage-provider-in-stead-of-cng-storage-provider) explains everything and you just need to follow the steps. In fact it's much more than just simple conversion of `pfx` container with `openssl`. I suggest to start following the article and try it again. At the end I cannot debug your issue, right? Best regards,

Comment: Thanks, @SlavaIvanov i got it working the problem was I wasn't making a new strong key name file.

Comment: Great work, glad you work it out.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov That tweakblogs article seems worthy of a full answer.

Comment: You right, this is valuable info somebody else may be looking for. I have added the answer and tried not just copy&paste  someone else intellectual work. I did the reference to the full article at the end. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signing identity stored in the `.pfx` container are most likely older "Cryptographic Service Providers" (CSP) style. The environment you are using to sign your package looks like required "Cryptography API: Next Generation" (CNG) provider type. The solution would be to convert your existing container to use CNG Storage Provider. This should be done by the following steps ...

- Import the PFX into your personal store
- Export the public key from the store by going through export wizard
- Export the private key using OpenSSL into `.pem` format

  ```
  openssl.exe pkcs12 -in <original pfx file>.pfx -nocerts -out <pem file location>.pem
  ```
- Convert to PVK

  ```
  pvk.exe -in <pem file location>.pem -topvk -strong -out <pvk file location>.pvk
  ```
- Merge the Public and Private keys

  ```
  pvk2pfx.exe -pvk <pvk file location>.pvk -pi <pvk password> -spc <pvk file location>.cer -pfx <new pfx file location>.pfx -po <pfx password>
  ```

Now you can import the newly created pfx file into the Certificate Manager. Make sure you remove the old certificate first from the Certificate Manager. Once the certificate is in place you can use certutil again to validate if the certificate is now correct.

If it now shows the provider as "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" you know the operation has been successful.

The credits goes to [Remy's Blog](https://remyblok.tweakblogs.net/blog/11803/converting-certificate-to-use-csp-storage-provider-in-stead-of-cng-storage-provider), where you may find the full explanation on the issue with examples and verification steps... [Converting Certificate to use CSP Storage Provider in stead of CNG Storage Provider](https://remyblok.tweakblogs.net/blog/11803/converting-certificate-to-use-csp-storage-provider-in-stead-of-cng-storage-provider).